# How to find a shortest path in a graph that while travelling it, you can "see" all the nodes within a radius

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, path, traversal

I have a 2d grid with some of the tiles being obstacles (walls), I want to be able to find the shortest path that allows you to go around the grid being able to see all of the other grids in the map with a radius of view. Here is a pixel art example (Blacks are the obstacles, gray is an arbitrary path).[image]

Comment: "to go around the grid": what do you mean ?

Comment: "radius of view"  Please specify this more clearly.  Suppose there were no obstacles - would a single point in the grid be able to "see" everywhere ( i.e. infinite line of sight ) or only the points within a certain distance ( i.e the path in an obstacle free grid would need a path along raster lines separated by twice the "radius of view" )

Comment: @ravenspoint only the points within a certain distance

Comment: Edit your question.  Do not hide important specs in comments.

Answer (score 1):

- Set R to be the "radius of view"
- Create orthogonal point grid with separation 2 * R
- Remove grid points that collide with obstacles
- Add connections from each point to the 9 or less closest points.  Do not connect across obstacles
- Calculate minimum spanning tree of remaining points.

Specify an "obstacle course" with a 20 by 20 gris, a view radius of 2 and three groups of abstacles

```
20 20 2
4 4
5 5
6 6
14 9
14 10
14 11
14 12
14 13
14 14
14 15
14 16
10 16
11 16
12 16
13 16
4 14
4 15
5 15
```

It looks like this

[image]

Adjacency list ( link id, node1 id, node2 id, distance )

```
l 42 47 5
l 42 142 5
l 47 52 5
l 47 152 7.07107
l 52 57 5
l 52 147 7.07107
l 52 152 5
l 52 157 7.07107
l 57 152 7.07107
l 57 157 5
l 142 242 5
l 142 247 7.07107
l 147 152 5
l 147 242 7.07107
l 147 247 5
l 147 252 7.07107
l 152 247 7.07107
l 152 252 5
l 157 257 5
l 242 247 5
l 242 342 5
l 247 252 5
l 247 347 5
l 257 357 5
l 342 347 5
l 347 352 5
l 352 357 5
```

Pass this graph into your favorite graph theory library to get the minimum spanning tree.

Here is the result when I use the [PathFinder](https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder3/wiki/Spans) application

[image]

The spanning tree is useful if, for example, the robot needs to return to a base frequently to recharge.  However, if your robot does not need to do this, then it involves a lot of unnecessary backtracking.

Calculation of a tour of the nodes that visits all of them with minimal backtracking can be done in various ways ( see *travelling salesman problem* ).  I use depth first searching of the spanning tree plus using the Dijsktra algorithm to find the nearest unvisited node when the robot gets trapped at a leaf of the spanning tree.  This quickly gives a reasonably effective result.

[image]

Application coded in C++, available at https://github.com/JamesBremner/obstacles